# How to download in a Colab R notebook a remote dataset from github?

Tags: r, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to download [this dataset](https://github.com/guyz/twitter-sentiment-dataset/blob/master/corpus.csv) from github in a colab R notebook.

I've tried using the magic `!git clone https://github.com/guyz/twitter-sentiment-dataset.git` but it does not work with an R notebook.

Are there any other possibilities to retrieve the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the following R code to download the file in your colab environment (the file is specified with its URL):

```
install.packages("R.utils")
library("R.utils")
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guyz/twitter-sentiment-dataset/master/corpus.csv", 
              "corpus.csv.gz")
gunzip('corpus.csv.gz')
```

After these instructions you will have the file `corpus.csv` containing the dataset.